# Dynamic 2D array and memory free

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I'm having a big troubles figuring out how to rightfully create a 2D dynamic array, how to assert the memory and how to free it in the end.

I'll show you parts of my code, and please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I declare on the dynamic array in main function and send it to BuildMatrix function that is supposed to assert the needed memory to the array and fill it.

that's how I declared on the array and send it to the function Build:

```
int row, column, i, j;
int **matrix; 
BuildMatrix(&matrix, row, column);
```

now thats BuildMatrix decleration:

```
void BuildMatrix(int*** matrix, int row, int column);
```

And that's how I assert the memory (row and column have values that the user chose)

```
matrix =malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
matrix[i] =malloc(column * sizeof(int));
```

Now so far everything works just fine, but when I try to free the memory, I get break point error

That's the function I used for freeing the memory:

```
void ExitAndFree(int** matrix, int row) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

The debugger show me that the error is on the first free (if I remove the first one, the second gives the error)

There is also another problem, but I think its to much for now, I'll ask later... :P

Thanks for your help!!

P.S: If you got any good tutorials about pointers and dynamic arrays (I'd rather 2D+ arrays) I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: So, where is the 2D array? There is none in the code shown. `int **` is no 2D array and cannot point to one. Being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment. `***` is typically a signal for wrong interface design.

Comment: Replace `matrix` with `*matrix`, or use a temporary variable `int **temp = *matrix` to make things slightly less mind bending. (You'll need a `*matrix = temp` at the end if using the temporary variable.)

Comment: @Olaf in the task I got, the function Build is declared as I posted, with 3 stars (***)

Comment: @user3386109 still doesnt work :X   I get acces violation error now

Comment: That sheds a bad light on the original author and  the quality of your course. Worse, if they indeed call that construct 2D array (dynamic or not does not make a difference). You should read a good (and modern, at least for C99, better the current version C11) C book. Your teacher seems to be stuck with C constructs which are obsolate since 18 years now (and was actually the worse of two possible workarounds back then). Feel free to cite me in class: Learn about VLAs.

Comment: I haven't said a word about my lecturer and you already figured it out... Yup my lecturer is really bad... Im learning everything on my own (and thats why Im so lake in knowledge..)

Comment: @MatanBenishty Why are you using `***`? Surely `**` for your matrix is fine.

Comment: @RoadRunner thats part of the task, thats what they want it to be for some reason

Comment: @MatanBenishty I guess that is fine. As others have said, your lecturer is not doing a good job if he wants you to use `***`. With that said, I guess you will be very good with pointers if you can use `***` pointers, I just think it is so unnecessary for what your trying to do.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yeah... Especially when you are new to that.. Ive been trying to work on that for so long...    I've reached another problem I cant figure out by myself whats wrong... When I enter same number of rows and columns it works smooth, but when they are not equal, I get error when I send "temp" array to free function .  BTW, do I actually need to free the array if its local array?

Comment: @MatanBenishty Basically anything you allocate with `malloc()`, you need to `free()` it.

Comment: @RoadRunner sigh... Well then I have 2 problems. The first one is when I enter to column higher number then row. It cause a writting location error.. ---------And the second is if I try to free the memory of the temp array, it gives me an error in the line" free(matrix);"

Comment: @MatanBenishty: So why not pick a good C book and ignore your lecturer? There is a list somewhere on SO. Find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a copy&paste ready example...

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void BuildMatrix(int*** matrix, int row, int column) {
    *matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        (*matrix)[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(int));
}

void ExitAndFree(int** matrix, int row) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int main()
{
    int row = 10, column = 10;
    int **matrix;
    BuildMatrix(&matrix, row, column);
    ExitAndFree(matrix, row);

    return 0;
}
```

However I would strongly recommend against working with raw pointers and separate variables for matrix directly. A better solution Software Engineering wise would be to either use an existing matrix library, or writer your own matrix library in C with struct...

Comment: I know! But right now in the task Im not allowed to use these libraries. Thanks a lot, Ill try that and see if it solve my problem

Comment: There is a problem in entering values to the array.  At matrix[1][0] im getting acces violation writing error

Comment: Could you show me your code? I ran valgrind with some array access and didn't get any error.

Comment: line 33: scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]); // TODO: <-- should be &((*matrix)[i][j])

Comment: EDIT: Ok I found out what was wrong!! Thank you so much, its working!! ----------------- But anyway, if you have a good tutorial with some more advanced examples of how to use 2D dynamic arrays and pointers, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: run `valgrind ./filename.exe -v`

Comment: Hey, could you please take a look in my code again?   When I try to free the temp array in the function Transpose (line 86), there is an error. --------------I found out that whenever row != column, I get that error, when they are even it works fine without any errors

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need a `***` pointer here, instead `BuildMatrix` could just return `**` to `main()`. This design change would make your program easier, as working with `***` can be a pain sometimes.

You also are not checking the return values of `malloc()` and `scanf()`, which can lead to future problems, and it's just safer to check those first. I also suggest you [Don't cast result of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), as this is not really needed in C.

With your errors of `free()` from the code you posted on @flintlock's answer, There is an inconsistency in your code:

You have declared:

```
void ExitAndFree(int** matrix, int row)
```

When this should be instead:

```
void ExitAndFree(int*** matrix, int row)
```

This change is needed in your code because you are calling `&matrix` in main for `ExitAndFree()`, so having `**matrix` in this function is not good enough. Again, this is because the code is using `***`, which makes life harder.

Your code seems to work [here](http://ideone.com/jP2zBY) with this change.

### With these recommendations, you can also implement your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **BuildMatrix(int row, int column);
void PrintAndFree(int **matrix, int row, int column);

int main(void) {
    int **matrix, row, column;

    printf("\nPlease enter number of rows:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &row) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid rows.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    printf("\nPlease enter number of columns:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &column) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid columns.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    matrix = BuildMatrix(row, column);

    PrintAndFree(matrix, row, column);

    return 0;
}

int **BuildMatrix(int row, int column) {
    int **matrix, rows, cols;

    matrix = malloc(row * sizeof(*matrix));
    if (matrix == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %d rows for matrix.\n", row);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        matrix[rows] = malloc(column * sizeof(*(matrix[rows])));
        if (matrix[rows] == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot allocate %d columns for row.\n", column);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter values to the matrix:\n");
    for (rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        for (cols = 0; cols < column; cols++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &matrix[rows][cols]) != 1) {
                printf("Invalid value entered.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

void PrintAndFree(int **matrix, int row, int column) {
    int rows, cols;

    printf("\nYour matrix:\n");
    for (rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        for (cols = 0; cols < column; cols++) {
             printf("%d ", matrix[rows][cols]);
        }
        free(matrix[rows]);
        matrix[rows] = NULL;
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(matrix);
    matrix = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I see, I'll add that. BTW, whats the difference between exit(1) to exit(EXIT_FAILURE)? Because we are doing it with exit(1)

Comment: They are very similar. `exit(1)` is for unsuccessful termination. `EXIT_FAILURE` just another way of doing the same thing. Just stick with `exit(1)`, it doesn't really matter much which one you use.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything man! I've learned a lot!      ---------------- Could you please take a look in my last reply to flintlock answer? I've reached another problem -_-'

Comment: @MatanBenishty, I have been looking at your code on codeshare, but I am a little confused as to what your trying to do with `void Transpose()`.

Comment: it need to transpose the matrix, if its 3x2, it will change it to 2x3

Comment: do you want to talk on facebook maybe? ill explain you everything